# ActionListener with a mousepress in java

Tags: java

I am trying to Make a action performed method activate when the mouse is pressed. is this possible. i can only find example like:

```
if(e.getsource() == button1){
....
}
```

can this method be activated by a mouseclick?

Comment: Have you tried the mouseListener class? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to your component (and then call the actionListener from its mouse clicked event.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

You may want to create a third function taking a `JComponent source` and having that containing your actionlistener code and being called by both your mouselistener and actionlistener.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code...

This will just print "Hi" to terminal every time you click whatever you put the mouseListener on. Replace contentPane with whatever you called it, and don't forget your import statements.

```
contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Hi");
  }
});
```